# Where can I find images of the Buttons?

Tags: qgis, references

I am trying to write a tutorial for simple QGIS functions. I would like to include a set of buttons, each with an explanation of what its function is. Can anyone tell me where I could find the buttons as an image, or would I need to print screen and cut up (digitally) each toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

The locations of icons would depend on your operating software, the version of your software, and the installer if you are on Windows.  I navigated to

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4
```

I did a search for .png and found the incons in several different locations.